# Relative include and library paths

Tags: software-installation

I am installing a program called voro++, but that is beside the point. The issue is, in the makefile that comes with this program there are these lines, which the author instructs you to modify as necessary:

/# Relative include and library paths for compilation of the examples

E_INC=-I../../src

E_LIB=-L../../src

Any idea if I should edit these?
I am unfamiliar with the concept of include and library paths, maybe I should look into that first.

This seems to be a very specific kind of issue, sorry about that and no hard feelings if the question doesn't make any sense to anyone. Here is the link to the software site: http://math.lbl.gov/voro++/about.html. Here is what the README says:

" To begin, the user should review the file "config.mk" in the top level
directory, to make sure that the compilation and installation settings are
appropriate for their system. Typing "make" will then compile the static
library, command-line utility, and examples. The command-line utility and
library will appear within the "src" directory."

I followed the steps exactly, and the program works fine. But why are there those " . . ." in the include and lib paths? Does that mean I should replace the ". . . " with something in particular?

Also, there is no / in "#Relative include . . ." part above. I had to put it, or else the site makes everything bold and large.
Thanks
Mel

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the link of the software you are trying to install? And also include all steps you took prior to bumping into this step. As your question currently stands it really lacks context for those not being able to read your mind, you see? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the  ... in the .../src are meant to indicate the path to the source files. It sounds like you compiled it properly from the top level directory of the distribution and it works so the full paths signified by the ... were unnecessary, or it's .. and not ... in which case .. indicates one level up from the current directory.